Android API 34 Security Exception - One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified
When the App runs in Android API 34, App crash with below error, but in API 33 it works fine, I tried many things including adding export=true to Android Manifest but failed to get it working any idea on this ?
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.npc.marry/com.xxx.ui.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: com.xxx: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
AndroidManifest is like
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false" />


public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginView {

//google sign in code
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
@NotEmpty
@BindView(R.id.edtUsername)
BlackEditText edtUsernamne;

@Password(min = 4)
@BindView(R.id.edtPassword)
BlackEditText edtPassword;

@BindView(R.id.btnLogin)
FancyButton btnLogin;

Validator validator;
LoginPresenter loginPresenter;


private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean result = intent.getBooleanExtra("result", false);
        if (result) {
            startActivity(MainActivity.class, null, true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Can not register your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    validator = new Validator(this);
    validator.setValidationListener(this);
    loginPresenter = new LoginPresenter(this, this, compositeSubscription);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LoginActivity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.result.notification"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LoginActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
...

}

you can set this globally like below

Create Class MainApplication.java or MainApplication.kt that extends android.app.Application
Open Android Manifest and add this to <application> tag like below

<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"


Override this method or use this

@Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
            return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
        } else {
            return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
    }


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
     registerReceiver(
         mReceiver, 
           new IntentFilter("com.result.notification")
           Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
        )
    } else {
        registerReceiver(
           mReceiver, 
           new IntentFilter("com.result.notification")
        )
    }

Add this code, specify Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED for Android 14 and above
